# IHTMLStyleSheetRulesCollection for style tags (inline styles)

Tags: delphi, dom, webbrowser-control, twebbrowser, ihtmldocument2

I use `IHTMLDocument2` interface to retrieve `IHTMLStyleSheetRulesCollection` using the `IHTMLDocument2::styleSheets` property. It works fine for retrieving styles within `<style>` tag (in document `<head>`).

I use the above to find all styles which have `backgroundImage` set (I need to read the value).

However, this collection doesn't include inline styles inside `<body>` like:

`<p style="background:url(image.jpg);"></p>` to extract "image.jpg" from this `<p>` tag.

What's the approach to scan entire DOM tree to find elements that have "style" property attached with background image? Code examples in C++ or Delphi are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to iterate `all` instead of `styleSheets` and take a look on the styles of the elements.

```
uses mshtml;

Procedure WebBrowserCreateStringListImagesFromElementStyles(const AWebBrowser: TWebBrowser; ResultList: TStrings; NoUrl: Boolean = false);
var
  nCount: Integer;
  element: IHTMLElement;
  elements: IHTMLElementCollection;
  bgImage: String;
begin
  Assert(Assigned(AWebBrowser.Document) and Assigned(ResultList));
  if Assigned(AWebBrowser.Document) then
  begin
    elements := (AWebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2).all;
    for nCount := 0 To Pred(elements.Length) do
    begin
      element := elements.item(nCount, '') as IHTMLElement;
      if (element.style.backgroundImage <> '') and (UpperCase(element.style.backgroundImage) <> 'NONE') then
      begin
        bgImage := element.style.backgroundImage;
        if NoUrl then
        begin
          if Pos('URL(', UpperCase(bgImage)) = 1 then
          begin
            Delete(bgImage, 1, Length('URL('));
            if Pos(')', bgImage) = Length(bgImage) then
              Delete(bgImage, Length(bgImage), 1);
          end;
        end;
        ResultList.Add(AnsiLowerCase(bgImage));
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Just one note, since the OP is looking for `body` elements, he may consider to iterate `Document.body.all`.

Comment: @kobik since the searched expression is invalid in <head> and would be moved to the <body> though you are right using `elements :=((AWebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2).body.all as IHTMLElementCollection);` would not make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort, translated to C++ and works great.